# How to share data between two websockets in python?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, twilio, flask-socketio

I have managed to successfully set up a websocket that connects to a Twilio server, which then streams a conversation I have to a phone number when I call it. The code then uses google speech-text API to transcribe the call and print it to my command line.

My next step is to stream each of the transcribed words to the 'home' route of the webpage as they are generated. So as I speak into the phone, the words will appear on the webpage.

My problem is that I cant seem to access the variable 'transcription' when setting up a separate websocket handler, which I would then use to update the 'home' route . socketio.emit doesn't seem to be connected to the socketio handler? Is this the best way? And does anyone know how I might go about this? The code within server.py that starts with a # is the code ive added to try and create the second websocket, and are the bits that aren't working as intended. My code is as follows:

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
from flask_sockets import Sockets
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

from SpeechClientBridge import SpeechClientBridge
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

import json
import base64
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "key.json"
HTTP_SERVER_PORT = 5000

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MULAW,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code='en-US')
streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
    config=config,
    interim_results=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)
#socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/twiml', methods=['POST'])
def return_twiml():
    print("POST TwiML")
    return render_template('streams.xml')

def on_transcription_response(response):
    if not response.results:
        return

    result = response.results[0]
    if not result.alternatives:
        return

    transcription = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    #session['newword'] = transcription
    print("Transcription: " + transcription)

@sockets.route('/')
def transcript(ws):
    print("WS connection opened")
    bridge = SpeechClientBridge(
        streaming_config, 
        on_transcription_response
    )

    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is None:
            bridge.terminate()
            break

        data = json.loads(message)
        if data["event"] in ("connected", "start"):
            print(f"Media WS: Received event '{data['event']}': {message}")
            continue
        if data["event"] == "media":
            media = data["media"]
            chunk = base64.b64decode(media["payload"])
            bridge.add_request(chunk)
        if data["event"] == "stop":
            print(f"Media WS: Received event 'stop': {message}")
            print("Stopping...")
            break

    bridge.terminate()
    print("WS connection closed")

#@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
#def test_connect():
    #word = session.get('newword',None)
    #socketio.emit('newword', {'newword': word}, namespace='/test')
    #print('Client connected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', HTTP_SERVER_PORT), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    print("Server listening on: http://localhost:" + str(HTTP_SERVER_PORT))
    server.serve_forever()
    #socketio.run(app)
```

streams.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://1812ce142529.ngrok.io/"></Stream>
     </Start>
     <Say>Thanks for calling!</Say>
     <Pause length="40"/>
</Response>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Live Transcription with Twilio Media Streams</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/css/application.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Live Transcription with Twilio Media Streams</h1>
  <img src="static/css/twilio-logo-red.png" />
  <img src="static/css/cloudspeechtotext.png" />

<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Asynchronous page updates will appear here:</p>
        <h3>Transcription:</h3>
        <div id="log">
        </div> <!-- /#log -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //connect to the socket server.
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    var words_received = [];

    //receive details from server
    socket.on('newword', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received word" + msg.word);
        //maintain a list of ten words
        if (words_received.length >= 10){
            words_received.shift()
        }            
        words_received.push(msg.words);
        words_string = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < words_received.length; i++){
            words_string = words_string + '<p>' + words_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
        }
        $('#log').html(words_string);
    });

});
```

Im fairly new to all this and have so far got by by throwing lots of bits of other peoples code together, hence why im now stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the server you are emitting an event named `word`, but in application.js you have a handler for the `newword` event. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You were correct with that inconsistency. I've updated the code in the question with the changes and my latest round of code iteration. The changes still don't work however.

Comment: I do not know if the servers started by the Flask-Sockets and Flask-SocketIO extensions are compatible, never seen anyone using both together. Maybe you should look into writing separate processes for the two servers, just to prevent any collisions between the two extensions.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do a similar-ish thing, but I'm unable to receive the media stream from Twilio, I'm using flask-socketio, however, I noticed you were using flask-sockets, did you try it with flask-socketio? Did it not work?